# Asus Eee pc 1005peb screen really dark despite brightness set to full

Tags: eeepc, asus

I have here an Asus Eee pc, model is the 1005peb version. Now for the most part it runs fairly decent and quick, not much issue with it except one major one.

Every time I restart or turn on the netbook my brightness is set to full yet my screen is like almost full on black, like it's turned off. I turn down the brightness a couple times using the Fn + F5/F6 keys and it goes nice and bright etc. When I turn the netbook on I have to turn down my brightness level to see the screen at what (I think) is full brightness and it's then ok. If I turn it off and restart etc I have to do it all over again.

Down is up kinda thing...it's an odd and annoying issue, one that I cannot find an answer for anywhere. So if anyone has a solid way of getting it fixed I would be most appreciative. Thanks!

- I'm using Ubuntu 11.04, Desktop Edition, Standard Grub settings and Kernel no changes to any of the hardcore system settings...
- I tried Ilari Kajaste's suggestion and it had no effect. Neither better nor worse.
- @fossfreedom I'll look deeper into your suggestion but at this time it looks almost the same as the second answer so I doubt it is what I currently seek.

Comment: Has your question been solved? I could reassign the bounty here if you want, since I got the bounty even though my solution did not fix your issue.

Comment: Nope it hasn't it just awarded it to someone....

Comment: @zkriesse - did you check your BIOS version and jupiter package as per my answer?  Finally enough I had a similar issue with my Toshiba running Lucid.  In the end I installed a newer kernel (2.6.37 vs 2.6.32) and this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with my Asus Eee PC 1001PX. The solution was to add `acpi_osi=Linux` to the computer bootup kernel options.

The bootup kernel options are controlled by the GRUB boot loader. You need to edit the grub settings at `/etc/default/grub` to have the following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_osi=Linux splash"
```

After editing the file, you need to make sure you run `update-grub` for your edit to take effect.

Hopefully this same solution works for you. If it doesn't, you can also try adding the option `acpi_backlight=vendor` to the same line which was also suggested to me when I tried to get the issue fixed.

Comment: Thanks but this didn't fix my issue. I found this the other day and gave it a shot but no go.

Comment: @zkriesse Ok. Well, hope you'll find the solution! I'll leave my answer here anyway, in case it'll help someone else with a similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

Some BIOS's are buggy - for example, [this bug-report](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+question/134371) mentions that a recent BIOS revision fixed brightness issues (revision 1202).  Suggest check the vendor website and install the latest available BIOS revision.

Even with a BIOS update, it is worth checking whether the standard eepc grub options still apply to your model

Try adding either `acpi_osi=Linux` [source](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianEeePC/Model/1005pe) or

`acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor` [source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EeePC/Fixes)

i.e.

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

add to the values above to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`

save

```
sudo update-grub
```

What you have described may point to general power-management issues.

Have you installed the `jupiter_0.0.50.2_all.deb` package on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jupiter/files/)?  More information about this can be found on [WebUp8](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/jupiter-ubuntu-ppa-hardware-and-power.html).

Comment: In my 1005PE the upgrade to bios 1202 fixed the problem, no need of any kernel parameters.

Answer (score 1):

What do your settings tell you in `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/lcd-brightness.conf`

> The lcd-brightness module allows you to control the brightness of  your
>          LCD screen.

```
   CONTROL_BRIGHTNESS
             When this option is enabled, laptop mode will adjust your LCD
             screen’s brightness settings, if possible. You must configure
             the following settings for this to work.

   BATT_BRIGHTNESS_COMMAND

   LM_AC_BRIGHTNESS_COMMAND

   NOLM_AC_BRIGHTNESS_COMMAND

   BRIGHTNESS_OUTPUT
             The  BRIGHTNESS_COMMAND settings specify commands that should
             be executed in order to set the brightness of your  LCD.  The
             BRIGHTNESS_OUTPUT  setting  specifies where the output of the
             command  will  be  written.  For  instance,  if  your   LCD’s
             brightness is adjusted by writing a numeric value 3 to a file
             called /proc/brightness, you should set the command to  "echo
             3"  and  the output file to "/proc/brightness". If your LCD’s
             brightness is adjusted using a utility  like  "toshset",  you
             should  include  the  entire  toshset  command  line  as  the
             command, and set the output file to "/dev/null".
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update for 13.10, kernel 3.11.0-19-generic, 32bit.**

I have a 1005PE:

```
    Manufacturer: ASUSTeK Computer INC.
    Product Name: 1005PE
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: 1005PE
    Family: Eee PC
```

with BIOS:

```
BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: 1202
```

and it works without any kernel command line parameters

```
[:~] % cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-19-generic root=[...] ro persistent quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

(I do not know what `persistent` do --- maybe a remnant of some old test).

I **do** have a couple of drivers running, but they are doing that automatically --- they  are loaded by the kernel without further help:

```
85% [:~] % lsmod | egrep -i "eee|asus"
eeepc_wmi              12983  0 
asus_wmi               23495  1 eeepc_wmi
sparse_keymap          13708  1 asus_wmi
video                  18777  2 i915,asus_wmi
wmi                    18590  1 asus_wmi
```

The laptop works ok (although better with xubuntu than the full fledged version); backlight, sound, suspend --- all the hw is working flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

it'a one abnormal behaviour on asus eeepc notebook with Fn brightness keys on ubuntu 14.04. when you press Fn+F5, or Fn+F6 keys to change brightness, brightness jumps almost twice. it's said about, it's a matter of performing brightness change action first by acpi and after that by Xserver, so the result is, brightness changes faster, in larger steps than you like or expect. for me have worked one slighlty different solution, change line at `/etc/default/grub` as many authors suggest, but insted of **`acpi_backlight=vendor`** use **`acpi_backlight=off`** use as well **`acpi_osi=Linux`** otherwise brightness change will not works totally.

There's no need to install `laptop-mode-tools` or other packages...
but this will cause, brightness change information slider doesn't appear as before (Xserver action is not performed), but brightness changes in normal, BIOS supported steps, it seems to me it's 10 steps at asus eeepc. maybe this can be solution on more problems you've posted.